# Login screen showing pre-filevault lock message

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, filevault

Before Filevault was on, I had a lock message set using ≪Set Lock Message≫:

[image]

After turning on Filevault, I changed the lock message.

However, I realize that when I restart the computer, the message is showing the old lock message.

**Why does this happen?**

How do I set it to use the new message?